# Prometheus Standard Deviation of Observed Value within a Time Range for a Histogram

Tags: prometheus

I'm calculating the average over a time range as follows:

```
sum(rate(my_hist_seconds_sum[5m])) / sum(rate(my_hist_seconds_count[5m]))
```

How would I similarly measure the standard deviation using "stddev"?

Comment: You don't. There is no way to recover the individual events in each measure. Any approximation would be of dubious accuracy.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelDoubez.  Unless someone can suggest an alternative, I plan on collecting duration metrics using both a Prometheus Historgram and a Gauge.  My understanding is that Histograms will allow me to create quantiles while Gauges can be used with the <aggregation>_over_time() functions including stddev_over_time.

Comment: Gauge gives you instant values so any stddev computed on them will only reflect the points of measure. In some way, you can get an approximate from histogram but not without caveat (see https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/issues/3998).

Comment: Thanks @MichaelDoubez.  Yes, I was unsure of the accuracy of a stddev computed from histogram buckets because of the bucket sizes as referred to in the issue you linked to.

Maybe I'm overthinking it, but I don't think I follow your comment about "only reflect the points of measure".  How could a stddev reflect points not measured?  I'm adding every measurement to the Gauge and thus my expectation is that the <aggregation>_over_time() functions will give me the most accurate result possible.

Comment: The gauge represents the instant value of a metric (by ex: free memory in bytes). The value collected in Prometheus is the current value when Prometheus polls the endpoint. If your value changes more often than the poll interval, changes in between will be lost. If you need the information, you need to compute the indicators in the application: that's the point of histogram and summary metrics. (https://prometheus.io/docs/concepts/metric_types/).

Comment: Note that if you have prior knowledge about the distribution of your data (such as normal distribution), you can have a good approximate of standard déviation from percentiles. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/104619/estimate-mean-and-standard-deviation-from-percentiles